# How to determine which software is performing the HTTPS scanning?

Tags: firefox, ssl, https

In my work computer, Firefox always gives me the "sec_error_unknown_issuer" error. This happens only on *all* HTTPS sites.

I have browsed Mozilla's support forums and understood that this is most probably caused by a software that performs an HTTPS scanning. The software presents its "fake" certificates to Firefox and hence, Firefox says that it does not know the issuer of these certificates.

However, I don't know which software is performing the HTTPS scanning and presenting its "fake" certificates to Firefox.

Is there a way to determine which software is performing the HTTPS scanning so that I will be able to add its certificates to Firefox and hence, be able to use the Firefox properly?

Comment: If it's all sites, it seems that it's either malware on your computer attempting to man-in-the-middle attack you or a browser extension gone rogue.

Comment: @RickViscomi I am in a work computer. The activity is _heavily_ monitored. So I am guessing that the reason is probably a software that performs HTTPS scanning.

Answer (score 1):

> In my work computer,...which software is performing the HTTPS scanning

This is probably legal SSL interception done by a firewall in your company. If you want to know the exact software used for scanning ask your local network administrator.

> ...  so that I will be able to add its certificates to Firefox and hence, be able to use the Firefox properly?

If you look at what certificates your server sends you have a look at the certificate details in the browser, especially at the chain certificates. But to make sure that what you get is really the companies certificate used for SSL interception and not some malicious man-in-the-middle attack you should verify your finding with your network administrator. And I'm pretty sure that if they do legal SSL interception they also help you do add the certificate to your browser - at least as long you are allowed to install alternative browsers to your computer and/or your own computer to connect to the companies network.

Comment: By the way, how can I understand which certificate is the one to verify with my network administrator? Because there are hundreds of certificates when I look at the certificates.

Comment: @Utku: You should not check against the certificates you have in the certificate store but the certificates sent when you access a specific site.  In firefox you can access it by using the "I understand the risks" part in the SSL warning, then "Add Exception" and there "View". In the dialog which opens use the Tab for "Details" to have a look at the certificate hierarchy. The relevant certificate is the one at the top.

Comment: But the problem is, there is no "Add Exception" button. Firefox (41.0.2) says: "This site uses HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) to specify that Firefox only connect to it securely. As a result, it is not possible to add an exception for this certificate."

Comment: @Utku: Then you have to find out another way how to add  your companies proxy CA. The best way is of course to ask your system administrators which certificate you should add. You can also check yourself with openssl, see https://isc.sans.edu/diary/Manual+Verification+of+SSLTLS+Certificate+Trust+Chains+using+Openssl/8686. Or you might try to access a site not protected by HSTS.